# scipy curve_fit vs. excel

Tags: python, excel, scipy

I have been trying `scipy.optimize curve_fit` and comparing it to the solver in Excel 2010.

While Python is much better for the large data sets I will eventually have, Excel's non-linear GRG solver seems to do a much better (and more reliable) job of fitting parameters than curve_fit for the smaller practice data sets I have. Excel seems always to converge to rational parameter guesses and curve_fit is prone to both wander off or settle on poor choices (much more initial condition dependent than Excel).

One of my fitting functions are:

```
def f(x,a,b,c,d,e,f):
    return a/(abs(b)+x)**abs(c) + d/(abs(e)+x)**abs(f)
```

where `x` is an array and `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` & `f` are the parameters.

I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations of ways to curve fit with scipy and numpy that may use other methods that are comparable in effectiveness to Excel's.

Comment: The quality of your results strongly depend on the structure of your data sets. If you do not know more about that structure, you could play with the different optimizers, Scipy offers (checkout http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize). It often helps, if you can put constraints on your variables, especially on the powers``c`` and `f``.

Comment: All those absolute values can really mess with curve fitting as well - do you really need them? A little understanding of the problem and where the parameters should be goes a long way to getting a good, stable fit.  To me the abs(x) are a sign that Excel isn't really doing a great job but you are forcing it to do something...

Comment: I'd be quite leery of using Excel for anything critical.  Investigators regularly find errors in various builtin stats functions; the fact that you can't read the source code is why most of us in the business use R, scipy, Matlab, or the like.  There are plenty of nonlinear solver packages for all those languages.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments: the upshot seems to me that I am better off using "minimize" rather than "curve_fit" and looking into how to add constraints as my use of abs() was just to get the solver from trying large negative numbers that were non-physical in its initial steps (it seemed to be harmless in practice, but I can do what I want more precisely with constraints). Thanks, Steve